# Mysteries of the skeleton trackers

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, tracking, skeleton

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey folks,

we are currently looking for a skeleton tracker we can use in our ROS project. We found these

- skeleton_markers -> works only with
  indigo, not with kinetic and is in
  “end-of-life”
- openni_tracker -> does not even work
  with indigo
- other stuff like the
  Chaos84/skeleton_tracker are oftern
  many years old as well and very
  poorly documented

What happened to them? Did they simply get out of fashion because something else replaced them or some companies bought some technologies (Apple)?

Do you know of a well maintained skeleton tracker already integrated in ROS or outside?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307787/mysteries-of-the-skeleton-trackers/) by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-11-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alterf](https://answers.ros.org/users/40521/alterf/) on 2019-03-19**:
Hi felixd,
Did you find something ?

**Comment by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) on 2019-04-05**:
@alterf Yeah, please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We finally ended up using the concepts [openni2_tracker](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_tracker/blob/hydro-devel/src/openni2_tracker.cpp) but had to heavily modify (=rewrite) it, since the code was so bad. Unfortunately I cannot release it publicly since I do not have the required rights to do so.

(Sorry for the late answer, I was very busy.)

---

Originally posted by [felixd](https://answers.ros.org/users/31644/felixd/) with karma: 26 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0